# There exists a measure such that the sum of derivatives is the integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is a homework question in functional analysis.

> If $n \geq 1$, show that there is a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n p^{(k)} \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) = \int p \, d \mu$ holds for every polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$. (Hint: you can use the fact that if $F$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$, then there is a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $F(f)=\displaystyle\int p \, d \mu$.)

The hint looks to me like we need to see that $F(f)= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n p^{(k)}\left( \dfrac{k}{n}\right)= p'\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) + p''\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) + \cdots + p^{(n-1)}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) + p^{(n)}(1)$. I am not really sure how to do this. Any hints in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for the Hahn-Banach Theorem because the above must hold only on a finite-dimensional subspace of $C[0,1]$, where it is sure to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to see is that the $F$ you wrote is a linear functional. For this, note that taking derivatives is linear, and so are evaluating at a point and adding.